# Why do some sentences have "thy" instead of "the"?

Tags: word-choice, pronouns, early-modern-english, archaic-language

I saw many times *thy* used instead of *the*, so why is that? When should I use it? What is the pronunciation of *thy*?

From the Bible (Christianity.SE)

> Thou shalt love the Lord **thy** God with all **thy** heart, and with all **thy** soul

And here on ELL.SE

> “I tell thee, Brother Nicodemus, **thy** offences are numberless as the
>   weeds which grow by the way-side. Here be many who have much to say of
>   thee : —speak, Brother Ulick!”
>
> —William Clarke, Three Courses and a Dessert, 1830

Comment: This question could be improved if you provided some examples of _where_ you saw this. "I saw many times" doesn't give us much to go on. I'm guessing it may have been Shakespeare or the Bible, though.

Comment: @J.R. sorry about that I'll add some examples.

Comment: Have you considered looking up words in a dictionary?  http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thy

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Thy* is not related to *the*. It is a possessive form of *thou*, which is, in turn, an archaic form of *you* (singular).

So, *thy* simply means *your*. Don't use it yourself unless your intent is making your speech outdated.

> Deny *thy* father and refuse *thy* name
>   -- Romeo & Juliet

I like the following quote, but don't treat it literally!

> If the Lord would show thee but this one thing, -- that to use "thee" and "thou" to a particular person is proper language, and Scripture language; and that to say "you," is improper, and arose from pride, and nourisheth pride, and so is of the world, and not of the Father; and thou should bow **thy** spirit to him in this one thing, thou little thinkest what a work it would make within thee, and how strongly the spirit of darkness would fight against **thy** subjection thereto.
>   -- Isaac Penington, 1670.

[Pronunciation](http://www.howjsay.com/index.php?word=thy).

As a good further reading I would recommend [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thou).

Also, there are some usage examples in ["Thou, Thee, Thy, Thine & Ye: Shakespearean English"](http://unenlightenedenglish.com/2009/07/thou-thee-thy-thine-ye-shakespearean-english).

Comment: If anyone's interested: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/224523/50720

Comment: What Penington is on about, in case it isn't clear, is that "properly" (which as often in arguments about English usage means "obsoletely" even in 1670), "ye/you" is plural and "thou/thee" is singular (I won't attempt the Old English orthography). Then "ye/you" came to signify deference/formality in the singular (and this is what "is improper, and arose from pride"), and eventually "you" replaced "thou/thee" entirely in many/most English dialects. Penington, like the authors of the King James Bible, feels that the original singular form avoids pridefulness

Answer (score 10):

[Thy](http://oaadonline.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/thy), which is an archaic or dialect word to say *your*, is nowadays used in certain religious groups and some traditional British dialects.
As English learner, you should not usually use it.

The *th* part is pronounced as in *this*; *y* is pronounced as in *my*. The IPA pronunciation of *thy* is /ðaɪ/.

Answer (score 0):

*Thy* is the possessive form of the second person singular pronoun. Its various forms are, as the subject: *thee*; object: *thou*; possessive: *thine*, *thy*; and reflexive: *thyself*.

The second person singular pronoun has fallen out of use in most English-speaking communities since the eighteenth century. As in several other languages, the forms were used in informal settings or when the person addressed was familiar. As class distinction became represented more by one's manners and customs, speech became more formal and use of the second person plural superseded use of the singular.

Thankfully, the same didn't occur for use of the first person plural.

Answer (score 0):

The Lord's Prayer in Old English with translation into an archaic English

[1] Fæder ūre þū þe eart on heofonum,

Father of ours, thou who art in heavens,

[2] Sī þīn nama ġehālgod.

Be thy name hallowed.

[3] Tōbecume þīn rīċe,

Come thy riche (kingdom),

[4] ġewurþe þīn willa, on eorðan swā swā on heofonum.

Worth (manifest) thy will, on earth as also in heaven.

[5] Ūre ġedæġhwāmlīcan hlāf syle ūs tō dæġ,

Our daily loaf do sell (give) to us today,

[6] and forġyf ūs ūre gyltas, swā swā wē forġyfað ūrum gyltendum.

And forgive us our guilts as also we forgive our guilters[22]

[7] And ne ġeled þū ūs on costnunge, ac āles ūs of yfele.

And do not lead thou us into temptation, but alese (release/deliver) us of (from) evil.

[8] Sōþlīċe.

Soothly (Truly).

You can read this in a better layout in en.wikipedia, Old English
(far down).

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_english